# ASP.NET MVC Dashboard for large dataset

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am creating a dashboard page to display more than 3k records in a single page. As fetching and displaying all 3k records at once is not good and slows down the page load, I am initially fetching 100 records and then on page load, I have following codes to load data for next pages. I am using kendo datasource and call the below function on dataSourceChanged event.

```
 function loadAllDashboardMeters() {

   var totalRecords = $('.jq-dashboard-meters-wrapper').data('total');
   var displayedRecords = dashboardDataSource.page() * dashboardDataSource.pageSize();// $('.meter-gauge-container').length;

    //if total records is greater than displayedRecords and request is not blocked
   if (totalRecords > displayedRecords && blockRequest == false) {

          //block next request
          blockRequest = true;

          //display bottom loader
          $('.jq-dahboard-loader').fadeIn();

          dashboardDataSource.page(dashboardDataSource.page() + 1);   
      }
}
```

It works fine, but the problem is I cannot scroll down (scrolling is blocked) until all 3k records are loaded on the page. Please suggest if there is better way to handle this so data loads in background without affecting user

Comment: I don't know KENDO but you seem to be using SYNCHRONOUS request , which blocks UI until the request is finished. So use ASYNCHRONOUS .

Comment: @JSantosh No, request is Async. Kendo just makes a jquery ajax call and return JSON data

Comment: check the code in jquery ajax call,  because jquery ajax can be used for sync and async requests using a parameter [ASYNC](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings)

Comment: @JSantosh I debugged codes, issue was not when we load data, issue was when I use JSON response and initialise another control for each record. That was blocking UI. Thanks